# Where can I find a decent jquery for treeview in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, treeview

I am looking for a treeview plugin for asp.net mvc.
I have found a plugin. http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

But generating the markup for this plugin isnt easy.
Is there any other plugin available?

Comment: Please, stop referring to ASP.NET MVC simply as "MVC". On is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It is like calling IE as "the internet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jstree](http://www.jstree.com/demo) is a nice plugin you can try out. The idea is to create the markup of nested `UL -LI` elements in your view as per the tree hierarchy and then invoke jstree method on the UL.

I wrote a [post](http://www.techiesweb.net/asp-net-mvc3-tree-view-with-jstree/) with step by step instruction how to create a treeview in ASPNET MVC  with jSTree plugin.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search and I've found this plugin:

http://www.jstree.com/demo